# How to get device phone number or unique id in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there anyway how can I detect device its phone number with Swift? It's because I want to get unique id of iOS device number for my app. In android, we can get device's secure id and its id never change whenever app is uninstalled and install again. For Swift, how can I get unique id or phone number then?

android unique id as well as secure id example

```
String deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

iOS Swift

```
var uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

Above line uuide will be change after re-installing app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple had to remove access to the device's UUID after a major privacy kerfuffle in the media.

Now there is a UIDevice call `identifierForVendor` that gets you pretty close. It's an ID that is unique for the current device from your app.

Comment: This ID is changing every time all apps from the same vendor are deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code

```
    let dID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault)
    let deviceID = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, deviceID) as NSString
```

Comment: Maybe you have to change deviceID to dID on the second row

Comment: This code is returning a different id each time you run your app. This isn't answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.1 can use

```
if let support =  NSClassFromString("FTDeviceSupport")?.value(forKey: "sharedInstance") as? NSObject  {

       support.value(forKey: "telephoneNumber")!



    }
```

Comment: This is private API usage, which violates App Store rule and commonly gets apps rejected. Even if it "gets away with it" one time, that does not mean the app won't be rejected when you try to update it. These kinds of privacy holes are also extremely fragile, as Apple tends to close more of them with every release. I do not recommend this technique.

Comment: it is true, private frameworks help us a lot in diagnosis, analysis, testing, etc - ,although we can’t use private API of iOS in product app,